# Cannot install c++ plugin in Netbeans 12 on Mac

Tags: c++, c, netbeans

I was trying to install C/C++ plugin version 1.30.6.1. This is what I got

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is anything can do - at least I couldn't find a solution. I'm using Qt Creator and VS Code instead. The only response I found was just "known bug wait for the next release"

Comment: Please, this question has nothing to do with C or C++ programming, but the plugin installation on netbeans.  It is not about programming at all.  and so, it shouldn't be posted here.

Comment: I would suggest installing NetBeans 11 and make sure that you have JDK 11 installed. The latest versions have compatibility issues with C++ and this is what worked for me after tons of online searches.